# Альтернатива ipset+iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Скачиваю с ipdeny.com 30 стран, которые я хочу залочить на сервере. Система падает (логично). Есть ли альтернатива этим пакетам?

Comment: Да вроде не очень логично.

Comment: Да вроде логично, что у вас ipset всю память сожрал. Сократите правила в ipset, путем перемещения в iptables до рабочего состояния.